# Use node.js plugin in Cordova

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cordova

I'm new to Cordova and am figuring out how to include a Node.JS Plugin, this one:

https://github.com/mateodelnorte/forecast.io

I've tried to include the JS file manually, but when running the code,

of course I get the error that `"require is not defined"`.

After Googling I found out that I have to use Cordova package manager to install such plugins.
however,

- there is no plugin for Forecast.io... So,
- how to use this nodejs-plugin?
- Do I need to create a Cordova plugin myself?

Comment: nodejs-plugin aren't compatible with Cordova. Different systems.